# AOSP emulator ANR when I press home or back

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source

when I press home or back in almost every application, it causes ANR, and then the emulator stopped forever. I really don't know why..

I started the emulator by

```
emulator -partition-size 4000 -memory 4096 -no-audio -accel on -http-proxy 127.0.0.1:1080
```

every architecture of emulator, arm, x86 and x86_64, has this problem.

I build the source on Ubuntu 14.04.

logcat contains `["Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3` and many others. (the traces.txt has so many text.. I think it's not proper to copy the whole content here..)

What is the problem? It's so confusing..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the machine you are running the emulator on have 4GBs of RAM? You are specifying that the emulator should use 4GB.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, it has. I set 4GB because otherwise the emulator often stopped :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.. I change the version of source from the latest to android-6.0.1_r20, the problem is gone. But I still don't know the reason.